# Action Required: Issue found: Invalid Data safety form , what is the solution?

Tags: android, google-play-services, policy

I recently received an email from Google Play Console about an issue with our app's Data Safety form. The issue seems to be related to discrepancies between the form and how our app collects and shares user data. Even if our app doesn't collect any user data, we are still required to complete an accurate Data Safety form.

Here's a summary of the problem:

Google Play Console has detected user data transmitted off the device, which we didn't disclose in our app's Data Safety form.
We need to ensure that our Data Safety section accurately reflects our data collection, sharing, and handling practices, including any third-party libraries or SDKs used in our app.
There's a warning about potential enforcement actions if we don't resolve this issue by November 17, 2023.
The issue details provided are as follows:

[image]

Here are the current dependencies in our app:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
```

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue. If anyone has experience with similar problems or insights into how to resolve it.